# How to rewrite htaccess flat link to real query url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I read a lot of Q&As here but failed to find a working solution. I want to change the URL from a flat link syntax to a "regular" query.

How do I get from this:

```
http://localhost/start/__developer/pages/12016652
```

to this:

```
http://localhost/start/__developer/pages/suche.php?objektnr=12016652
```

by either means of htaccess or PHP? Disregard the curlies please. Thanks in advance for your support!

**At this point I'm trying this:**

```
Options        +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase    /start/__developer/immo-shg-v4/pages/
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)$ suche.php?objektnr=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

**Solution:**

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ suche.php?objektnr=$1 [L,NC,NE,R]
```

The [R] flag forces a redirect.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable .htaccess through your httpd.conf it is not already enabled and put these lines in the .htaccess file in DOCUMENT_ROOT folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
#This is your redirect rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)objektnr=([^&]*)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(start/__developer/pages/)([^/]*) $1suche.php?objektnr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

As per your comments below have another RewriteRule like this:

```
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)objektnr=([^&]*)(?:&|$) [NC]
#This is your modified redirect rule
RewriteRule ^(start/__developer/immo-shg-v4/pages/)([^/]*) $1suche.php?objektnr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: And if you only want to allow numbers, use `[0-9]` instead of `[^/]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not yet working though. I get a `The requested URL /start/__developer/immo-shg-v4/pages/12016652 was not found on this server.` Well, of course it can't be found, since it's not a real location. That's what I got with my own tryouts too. Any idea?

Comment: Obviously it won't since you question has URI: `/start/__developer/pages/12016652` but you are trying to redirect `/start/__developer/immo-shg-v4/pages/12016652` with extra **/immo-shg-v4** in between.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a rule for the new URI you have. Pls check.

Comment: Oh boy! Shame! Thanks for catching this so fast. Unfortunately I remain getting a "404 Not Found". `The requested URL /start/__developer/immo-shg-v4/pages/12024635 was not found on this server.`

Comment: Are you able to open URI: `/start/__developer/immo-shg-v4/pages/suche.php?objektnr=12024635` ?

Comment: **Yes I am!** It's the URI syntax everything works just fine with. All I want to provide is for users to be able to click flat links which translate to this query syntax. The full working address: `http://localhost/start/__developer/immo-shg-v4/pages/suche.php?objektnr=12024635`

Comment: **This is working** `RewriteBase /start/__developer/immo-shg-v4/pages/ RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ suche.php?objektnr=$1 [QSA,L]` One problem remains, it results in am URI like this: `../pages/12024635/?objektnr=12024635` instead of the desired `../pages/suche.php?objektnr=12024635`. Hmm? Is it rather a Redirect, then a Rewrite, I am looking for?

Comment: Thanks again! I made it work with this line as of now:
`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ suche.php?objektnr=$1 [L,NC,NE,R]`